# 'Error occurred during a cryptographic operation' during local IIS deployment of ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I realize there are other threads related to this question but I've tried all the solutions I could find in those threads to no avail.  I have a ASP.NET site that was built using the default template Visual Studio provides for Authenticating against an Active Directory.  I then attempted to deploy it to a local IIS on my machine. However I get this error when I deploy.  I can run it locally fine on IIS.  I deployed the stock ASP.NET program authenticating against the same AD on the same local IIS on a different port and it works fine. However my app still errors out even though all the configs between the two are the same.  Both are using HTTPS via the development certificate. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add machine key entry in the web.confile file like below:

```
    <configuration>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <machineKey decryptionKey="Enter decryption Key here" 
                    validation="SHA1" 
                    validationKey="Enter validation Key here" />
      </system.web>  
   </configuration>
```

if you still get the error then try to set the LoadUserProfile=true in iis application pool advance setting.

below is the script to generate the machine key:

```
 # Generates a <machineKey> element that can be copied + pasted into a Web.config file.
function Generate-MachineKey {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param (
    [ValidateSet("AES", "DES", "3DES")]
    [string]$decryptionAlgorithm = 'AES',
    [ValidateSet("MD5", "SHA1", "HMACSHA256", "HMACSHA384", "HMACSHA512")]
    [string]$validationAlgorithm = 'HMACSHA256'
  )
  process {
    function BinaryToHex {
        [CmdLetBinding()]
        param($bytes)
        process {
            $builder = new-object System.Text.StringBuilder
            foreach ($b in $bytes) {
              $builder = $builder.AppendFormat([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, "{0:X2}", $b)
            }
            $builder
        }
    }
    switch ($decryptionAlgorithm) {
      "AES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider }
      "DES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.DESCryptoServiceProvider }
      "3DES" { $decryptionObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider }
    }
    $decryptionObject.GenerateKey()
    $decryptionKey = BinaryToHex($decryptionObject.Key)
    $decryptionObject.Dispose()
    switch ($validationAlgorithm) {
      "MD5" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACMD5 }
      "SHA1" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1 }
      "HMACSHA256" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256 }
      "HMACSHA385" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA384 }
      "HMACSHA512" { $validationObject = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512 }
    }
    $validationKey = BinaryToHex($validationObject.Key)
    $validationObject.Dispose()
    [string]::Format([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
      "<machineKey decryption=`"{0}`" decryptionKey=`"{1}`" validation=`"{2}`" validationKey=`"{3}`" />",
      $decryptionAlgorithm.ToUpperInvariant(), $decryptionKey,
      $validationAlgorithm.ToUpperInvariant(), $validationKey)
  }
}
```

save this script. tha load the file.

```
PS C:\windows\system32> C:\Untitled1.ps1
```

Run below command:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Generate-MachineKey -validationAlgorithm SHA1
```

You could refer below article for more detail:
[Resolving view state message authentication code (MAC) errors](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors#AppendixA)